# Jquery Loading an eq(i) from an external html possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to load data from an external html file into a div. I would like to match the eq number of the external .sbool div to the internal .kontrollwert div, but I don't know how to adress that external div by the .eq() method. Using

```
.load('variable.html .sbool'.eq(i))
```

does not work. Is there another way to get that result?

This is what I have:

```
var kontrollwertmenge = $('.statusbezeichnung').length;

for (i=0;i<kontrollwertmenge;i++) {
    $('.kontrollwert').eq(i).load('variable.html .sbool');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i=0;i<kontrollwertmenge;i++) {
    $('.kontrollwert').eq(i).load('variable.html .sbool:eq('+i+')');
}
```

Comment: That gets the results I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this way -

```
$.get('variable.html',function(data){
   $('.kontrollwert').eq(i).html($(data).find('.sbool').eq(i));
});
```

Comment: I assume I should substitute this for  $('.kontrollwert').eq(i).load('variable.html .sbool'); within the 'for loop'? That did not seem to work for some reason.